Using EF Core, select rows that match multiple columns
I have an EF Core table that I want to search
Table A
AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD
---------------------
Jon | Dog | 100 | 321 
Rob | Cat | 234 | 236
Tom | Cow | 456 | 768
Sly | Rat | 843 | 698

I also have a list of objects
Prop1 | Prop2
-------------
Rob   | Cat
Tom   | Fly
Tom   | Rat
Jon   | Dog

I want to search table A where Prop1 and Prop2 match column AAA and BBB. So in the example only the following rows in table A will show:
AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD
---------------------
Jon | Dog | 100 | 321 
Rob | Cat | 234 | 236

Is there a way of using EF Core to do this? Rather than returning all the table data and programmatically iterating the results to find the records.

This question is similar to: How to filter entities by collection containing two columns?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

you can achieve this using .Where and .Any to match TableA rows against your list of objects without loading all data into memory.
public class YourObjectType
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

List<YourObjectType> data = new List<YourObjectType>
{
    new YourObjectType { Prop1 = "Rob", Prop2 = "Cat" },
    new YourObjectType { Prop1 = "Tom", Prop2 = "Fly" },
    new YourObjectType { Prop1 = "Tom", Prop2 = "Rat" },
    new YourObjectType { Prop1 = "Jon", Prop2 = "Dog" }
};

var results = await context.TableA
    .Where(a => data
        .Any(c => c.Prop1 == a.AAA && c.Prop2 == a.BBB))
    .ToListAsync();

